# Rails Controller: Is it good practice to define controller for associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller, model-associations

Suppose i have mapping table map_*user*_roles. I have defined models Role and User. Both are associated to each other by relationship has_and_belongs_to_many. Of course it does not make sense to define model for mapping table in rails. 
I have defined users_controller and roles_controller for crud operations on user and role respectively.

For association of user-role, what should i do? Should i define separate controller like user_roles_controller or should i make modifications in Role and User controller(if so how to do so) ? 
Please suggest, what is good practice. Examples and good links would be great help
Thanks for devoting time.

Comment: What should the controller be doing?

Comment: It should perform Create, Delete, Retieve operations on User-Role assoication

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what a separate controller for the association would offer that couldn't be achieved with your existing `UsersController` and `RolesController`. Also, note that sometimes is does make sense to define a model for the mapping table, that's what the `has_many :through` association is for. You should use it if you need to store extra attributes against the join model.

Comment: Please give some code description for how should i retrieve user-role collection as params and update same on model.

Comment: I am using it wherever required. Infact when i defined model for mapping table(in case some extra attributes), there i have define separate controller for CRUD on same model.

Comment: @Maddy.Shik You shouldn't need to create the mapping table model directly. Instead you should be creating it through the association using the `collection.build` or `collection.create` methods. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html